# Using GDB to display entire int array

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging using GDB. I know while debugging we can:
if `char arr[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` then use `display /s arr` in GDB to display `{a, b, c}`  for every stop in the debugger.

But how to display an array of ints using display? so that I get the entire array contents in every stop? For example if `int arr[4] = {4, 3, 2, 1}`.

How do I display the entire arr using the GDB display function so that the whole arr appears each stop?
So that every stop I see:

`{4, 3, 2, 1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GDB you can type in 
`display /d *arr@4`
This will display
`{4,3,2,1}` where `@4` displays 4 addresses in arr
while 
`display /d arr[0]`
will just display the first index of arr